# Template error in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js and using vue.js to update a `<li>` list on selection of elements from other list using vue.js. But I am getting error

```
vue.js:465 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
```

here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/technosml/eywraw8t/65484/).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error says it. You can't use v-model on li element.

Comment: ok, so is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Remove the v-model attribute. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: I want to create a functionality like in this page, where user can add multiple items to cart list. https://ruuby.com/provider/urn:ruuby:therapist:846389465-1. Hiw can I achieve this in Vue.

Comment: If you have any more issues make a separate question. The one you asked is solved by removing v-model.

Comment: Thanks @FINDarkside

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you can't have v-model attribute on `li` element. So simply remove the `v-model="selectedTasks"`.